# How to cross-compile external kernel modules whe the kernel build is out-of-tree?

Tags: kernel-module, kbuild

On an x86_64 host I have cross-compiled a Linux kernel for an ARM target out-of tree. So I have two directories:

1. ~/kernel_git_repo/ - contains kernel source only
2. ~/kernel_buld_dir/ - contains the .config file and built kernel objects

In a third directory

1. ~/external_module - sources for an external kernel module

I have the source code for an external module, with a Makefile.

The "usual" command for an **in-tree built kernel** would be:

```
make -C <path-to-compiled-src-code> M=$(PWD) modules
```

For my **out-of-tree built kernel**, neither ~/kernel_git_repo/ nor ~/kernel_buld_dir/ work as `<path-to-compiled-src-code>`. It appears that the make command needs **both** the kernel source repo with the Kbuild infrastructure **and** the build directory with the `.config` file and the objects.

In this situation, what is the make command to use in the ~/external_module/Makefile for building the module?

Comment: You should use `make -C ~/kernel_build_dir` always when you did build your kernel with `make O=~/kernel_build_dir`.

Comment: Also, you need to provide an excerpt with the actual error that happens in the case I described in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's essentially the same,

```
$(MAKE) -C  $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(shell pwd) modules
```

except

```
KDIR=/path/to/kernel/source
```